# python encoding and decoding strings

Tags: python, string

I am reading a first and last name in Python from a file and am having trouble with encoding. I want to print out the name, but am getting "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u021b' in position 11: character maps to undefined" with this code:

```
    first = obj.first_name.encode('utf-8')
    last = obj.last_name.encode('utf-8')
    first = first.decode('utf-8')
    last = last.decode('utf-8')
    print(first)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your output terminal/console doesn't have any way of displaying `ț`. Try `chcp 65001` before running the script if you're using Windows.